# Filtering DbSet in EntityFramework CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, dbcontext

This is the ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public UserTypes Type { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get { return $"{Firstname ?? ""} {Lastname ?? ""}".Trim(); } }
}
```

We have 3 different UserTypes (Provider, Supporter, NormalUser **(which is the ApplicationUser)**)

```
public class Provider : ApplicationUser{
   // Provider related virtual Icollections
}

public class Supporter : ApplicationUser{
   // Supporter related virtual Icollections
}
```

Now in the `ApplicationDbContext` I want to have these `DbSet`s beside ApplicationUser:

```
public virtual DbSet<Provider> Providers{get;set;}
public virtual DbSet<Supporter> Supporters{get;set;}
```

Which `DbSet<Provider>` should return the `ApplicationUsers` that their `UserTypes` equals 2 (for example)

Comment: What are the properties of UserTypes?

Comment: @H.Herzl well it is an enum `{ Normal = 1, Provider = 2, Supporter = 3}`

Comment: Have you tried this? var query = dbContext.Providers.Where(item => item.Type == UserTypes.Provider).ToList();

Comment: This is what I have always done. I want to make it a virtual DbSet with its own unique Properties (something like views in the sql)

Comment: I don't understand, have you tried that code and doesn't work?

Comment: No, I don't want to use that code. I want to have `Providers`  in my DbContext with its own related ICollections. and not have to filter the `users` each time

Comment: If I get your point, you can solve your issue with extension methods to retrieve data because you don't want to create views from database side, but you'll need to have a method to filter the data; according to my knowledge there isn't equivalence for views in ef

Comment: @H.Herzl I found the answer. I thought you may like to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
     public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole<long>, long>
        {

            public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
                : base(options)
            {
            }
            public ApplicationDbContext()
                : base()
            {
            }

            public virtual IEnumerable<Provider> Providers
            {
                get
                {
                    return (IEnumerable<Provider>)Users.Where(z => z.Type == UserTypes.Provider).AsEnumerable();
                }
            }
         }
```